# Rights of others

Tags: fatwa

I wanted to know, i rented a hotel with another friend. The hotel booking was under my name and because i am of a western nationality, the room did not have to pay a tourist fee. I shared the room with my friend from asian nationality and forgot to disclose it to the hotel.  If the hotel knew, then the room would be charged a tourist fee where i would have asked my friend to pay it. 
Can i know that since the hotel says both people who rent the hotel room are liable the tourist fee, am i still responsible to pay the fee on the room in allahs eyes? As my friend was the one who was charged because she was from a different nationality. I have lost contact with that friend, so if i dont pay is this considered not returning the rights of the hotel?

Comment: Need to add that this happened 4 years ago. My concern is about the rights of the hotel. Will i be in trouble with allah for not fullfilling the rights of the hotel or will it be my friend. Or is it since the hotel didnt know we should just let his go and allah will repay the hotel in the here after

Answer (score -1):

Assalam aleykum brother, this should be a comment, but I have no reputation for it. So here goes:

You should at least inform the person that the stay there entails additional costs. 
And after that the next step would be to have the confirmation of the person who will pay that cost. So that there is no late liability, or lack of information about the possible debts to the Hotel. Everything must be made clear so that there is no unnecessary concern.